# How to make Eclipse 4.7 run smooth on server-jre-1.8... on Linux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, java-8

I have read a lots documentation and specification on Oracle jre-8. Want to make Eclipse run faster in long usage run time, means start up time not so significant - using more memory. For 6gb pc I decided 2gb maximum for IDE, since browser and web server also need some.

Installed Eclipse PDT 4.7 and many modules. Should be the same for versions of Eclipse using jre-8. Installed server-jre-1.8 from oracle. Also installer jre to upacking it in home folder, while system java is another, and pointing eclipse ini to that install location.

Comment: __Not duplicate__, as other questions/answers refer to old versions.

Comment: **Possible** duplicate, since the same answers would apply.

Comment: __Same__ doesnt contain such G1C configuration/optimization. Also with comments, so possible to do self job depending on IDE environment version/usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only applicable to oracle latest Java 8, and Eclipse 4.7.2. (older eclipse versions may also work, if they use oracle jre-1.8) Using around 1gb of memory, maximum(never reached) 2g. It can run on less or more memory with modifications, not only xmx, xms. GC runs less often and so makeing Eclipse run more smooth. Starting are long, and also first opening some perspective fast but next time much faster.

This also can work fine for Oracle 9, but need some modifications.

eclipse.ini: (with doucumentation, you can remove it if causing problem)

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
#Turn off splash. Better for Ubuntu Unity
-nosplash
#-showsplash
#org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
#
#client or server VM
#-client
-server
-vm
/home/lenya/Java/server-jre-1.8.0_162-oracle/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
#
#Enable the G1 Collector
#Configured for oracle java 8, lower response time
#Using docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods
-XX:-UseLoopPredicate
-XX:+UseG1GC
#
#This is interpreted as a hint to the garbage collector that pause times of <nnn> milliseconds or less are desired.
#The garbage collector will adjust the Java heap size and other parameters related to garbage collection in an
#attempt to keep garbage collection pauses shorter than <nnn> milliseconds. By default there is no maximum pause
#time goal. These adjustments may cause garbage collector to occur more frequently, reducing the overall throughput
#of the application. The garbage collector tries to meet any pause time goal before the throughput goal. 
#In some cases, though, the desired pause time goal cannot be met.
#__For lower response time - more maximum pause__ __Larger heap needed__
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=5000
#
#The throughput goal is measured in terms of the time spent collecting garbage and the time spent outside of garbage
#collection (referred to as application time). The goal is specified by the command-line option -XX:GCTimeRatio=<nnn>.
#The ratio of garbage collection time to application time is 1 / (1 + <nnn>). For example, -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 sets
#a goal of 1/20th or 5% of the total time for garbage collection.
#
#The time spent in garbage collection is the total time for both the young generation and old generation collections combined.
#If the throughput goal is not being met, then the sizes of the generations are increased in an effort to increase the time
#that the application can run between collections.
# __Larger heap needed__
-XX:GCTimeRatio=99
#
#Sets the Java heap occupancy threshold that triggers a marking cycle.
#Percentage of the (entire) heap occupancy to start a concurrent GC cycle. It is used by G1 to trigger a concurrent GC
#cycle based on the occupancy of the entire heap, not just one of the generations. 
#A value of 0 denotes 'do constant GC cycles'. The default value is 45
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
#
#Sets the occupancy threshold for an old region to be included in a mixed garbage collection cycle.
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=80
#
#Sets the percentage of heap that you are willing to waste. The Java HotSpot VM does not initiate the 
#mixed garbage collection cycle when the reclaimable percentage is less than the heap waste percentage
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=10
#
#Sets the target number of mixed garbage collections after a marking cycle to collect old regions with
#at most G1MixedGCLIveThresholdPercent live data. The default is 8 mixed garbage collections.
#The goal for mixed collections is to be within this target number
#-XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=64
#
#Sets an upper limit on the number of old regions to be collected during a mixed garbage collection cycle.
#The default is 10 percent of the Java heap
-XX:G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent=5
#
#G1 creates a false ceiling by trying to leave the reserve memory free in case more 'to-space' is desired
#__Ajust depending on heap size__
-XX:G1ReservePercent=15
#
#Sets the percentage of the heap to use as the minimum for the young generation size. The default value is 5 percent of your Java heap
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=5
#Sets the percentage of the heap size to use as the maximum for young generation size. The default value is 60 percent of your Java heap
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=50
#
#Sets the number of parallel marking threads. Sets n to approximately 1/4 of the number of parallel garbage collection threads (ParallelGCThreads).
#Number of threads concurrent garbage collectors will use. 
#The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
#
#Sets the value of the STW worker threads. Sets the value of n to the number of logical processors. 
#Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage collectors.
#The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
#
#With G1 the Java heap is subdivided into uniformly sized regions. This sets the size of the individual sub-divisions.
#The default value of this parameter is determined ergonomically based upon heap size. 
#The minimum value is 1Mb and the maximum value is 32Mb. The goal is to have around 2048 regions based on the minimum Java heap size.
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1m
#
#Sets the thread stack size.
-Xss16m
#
#Specifies the initial size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.
#__Disable it for auto configuration, changed at run time__
-Xms1g
#
#Specifies the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool.
#__Do avoid swapping__ __Set less, and tune GC__
-Xmx2g
#
#Sets the mode of the bytecode verifier. Bytecode verification ensures that class files are properly formed and
#satisfy the constraints listed in section 4.10, Verification of class Files in the The Java Virtual Machine Specification.
#Do not turn off verification as this reduces the protection provided by Java and could cause problems due to ill-formed class files.
-Xverify:none
```